# How to change dictionary outside the funchion, if I redefine it inside?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.6
I have a code with lots levels of functions. In all of them I use one dictionary, provided as argument. So, if i change it somewhere, it changes everywhere down the levels. But, in one function I need replace it with another one, and thats where problem appeared: redefine dictionary inside, brokes link to the main dict, and doesnt change it down the levels. Also, I cant use return, since it's will redefine dictionary, just one level down.

So:

```
Test = {"1":"2"}

def Teser(Test):
    Test["Hell"]= "No"

Teser(Test)
print(Test)
```

this outputs:

```
{'1': '2', 'Hell': 'No'}
```

But

```
Test = {"1":"2"}

def Teser(Test):
    Test = {"Hell":"No"}

Teser(Test)
print(Test)
```

otputs (with, and without return):

```
{'1': '2'}
```

Is there a way to make second code result same as first one, without return or globals?

Comment: Perhaps this is time to refactor the code? If not, this variable, does it have to use the same name as the global dict when doing local work?

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to be that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reassigning the parameter, not the global variable, which is just bad practice anyway

Its equivalent to this, and expecting `Test` to change

```
Test = {"1":"2"}
def Teser(t):
    t = {"Hell":"No"}
Teser(Test)
```

Even if that did work, you'd lose the key `"1"`, which I'm not sure is part of the problem...

In any case, it's recommended to use a global here and a different parameter name

```
Test = {"1":"2"}
def Teser(t):
    # you can still reference t values, if needed 
    global Test  # while not necessary, it clarifies which variable scope is used 
    Test = {"Hell":"No"}
Teser(Test)
print(Test)
```

And note: only classes should be capitalized, not variables and functions

Comment: You should probably lowercase the dictionary and function

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
Test = {"1":"2"}

def Teser(Test):
    Test.update({"Hell":"No"} , last = True)

Teser(Test)
```

This will add the key "Hell" at the begin of your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make second code result same as first one, without return or globals?

In most cases you should probably be using `return`. However, if the functions are very nested, it might be easy to simulate globals using hanging classes:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        SomeClass.test = {"1": "2"}

    @classmethod
    def teser(cls, test):
        cls.test["Hell"]= "No"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a global variable you wouldn't want to pass it as a parameter. If you pass it the method creates a local variable named "Test" and only modifies it. Even if you dont pass it as a parameter it will create a local variable. To use the global variable write `global variable_name` at the start of your method.

```
Test = {"1":"2"}

def Teser():
    global Test
    Test = {"Hell":"No"}

Teser()
print(Test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a x.update method on your dic like:

```
def Teser(Test):
    Test.update({'Hell':'No'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirements correctly, you need to use a local dict with the same name, and once the work is done, somehow update the global too, before calling something else.

```
Test = {"1":"2"}

def update_global(local_dict):
    global Test
    Test.update(local_dict)
    return Test

def Teser(Test):
    Test = {"Hell":"No"}
    #do work
    Test_local = Test.copy() #incase you still need to access the local variables for some reason
    Test = update_global(Test)
    #do some other work. If you need the local test back, just reassign.

Teser(Test)
print(Test)
#{'1': '2', 'Hell': 'No'}
```

This code may need a refactoring though, The names should not be this tightly coupled inside functions if you can help it.